# Inserção de PDF

Tags: php, pdf, inserir

Estou com um problema no código de inserção de PDF, pois o nome do ficheiro não é enviado para a base de dados.
O código a que me refiro é este:

Formulário:

```
<form  id="novoEventoForm" action="?page=docs_com&insert=new" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$pathToSave = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "psoeiras.pt/documentos/";

/*Checa se a pasta existe - caso negativo ele cria*/
if(!file_exists($pathToSave))
{
    mkdir($pathToSave);
}

if( $_FILES ) 
{ // Verificando se existe o envio de arquivos.

    if( $_FILES['new_texto'] ) 
    { // Verifica se o campo não está vazio.

        $dir = $pathToSave; // Diretório que vai receber o arquivo.
        $tmpName = $_FILES['new_texto']['tmp_name']; // Recebe o arquivo temporário.

        $name = $_FILES['new_texto']['name']; // Recebe o nome do arquivo.

        preg_match_all('/\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+/', $name , $extensao);
        if(!in_array(strtolower(current(end($extensao))), array('.txt','.pdf', '.doc', '.xls','.xlms')))
        {
             echo ('Permitido apenas arquivos doc,xls,pdf e txt.');
        }

        // move_uploaded_file( $arqTemporário, $nomeDoArquivo )
        if( move_uploaded_file( $tmpName, $dir . $name ) ) 
        { // move_uploaded_file irá realizar o envio do arquivo.               
            echo ('Arquivo adicionado com sucesso. ' );                  
        } else 
        {                  
            echo ('Erro ao adicionar arquivo.' );                    
        }

    }

}
```

E o formulário para a inserção do PDF é este

```
<span for="new_texto" style=" display: block; float: left;    padding: 10px;  margin-top: 10px;       padding-top: 8px;     height:20px;  padding-bottom: 7px;    background-color: #111; position: absolute;     /* color: beige; */     width: 79px;       text-align: center;  /* padding-left: 25px; */">Documento</span>
<input type="file" name="new_texto" value=""  style="color:black; display: block; border-radius: 0px; outline-color: #0489b1; margin-left: 101px; margin-top: 10px;  width: 472px;"/>
```

Código para Inserir PHP

```
if($_GET['insert'])
    {   
      $new_pagina = strip_tags(trim($_POST['new_pagina']));
        $new_etiqueta = strip_tags(trim($_POST['new_etiqueta']));
        $new_dia = strip_tags(trim($_POST['new_dia']));
        $new_mes = strip_tags(trim($_POST['new_mes']));
        $new_ano = strip_tags(trim($_POST['new_ano']));
        $new_titulo = strip_tags(trim($_POST['new_titulo']));
        $new_texto = strip_tags(trim($_POST['new_texto']));
        $new_tipo = strip_tags(trim($_POST['new_tipo']));




        $updateSlideshow = mysql_query("INSERT INTO documentos
                                        VALUES('',
                                                '".mysql_real_escape_string($new_pagina)."',
                                                '".mysql_real_escape_string($new_etiqueta)."',
                                                '".mysql_real_escape_string($new_dia)."',
                                                '".mysql_real_escape_string($new_mes)."',
                                                '".mysql_real_escape_string($new_ano)."',
                                                'on',
                                                '".mysql_real_escape_string($new_titulo)."',
                                                '".mysql_real_escape_string($new_texto)."',
                                                '".mysql_real_escape_string($new_tipo)."',
                                                ''

                                                 ) ") or die('1.7231»'.mysql_error()); 
    }
```

Comment: Onde está o código de envio para a Base de Dados?

Comment: Não está aqui representado

Comment: Mas como quer que vejamos o problema sem esse código?

Comment: Ja editei o código acima e está lá a parte de inserir o conteudo

Comment: Não estas a usar a variável `$name` em lado nenhum.

Comment: Entao em vez de usar $name, uso qual? $new_texto??

Comment: Resultou a minha resposta?

Comment: Sim sim resultou muito obrigado

Comment: E outra pergunta, no campo da minha base de dados, tenho umas div e agora desformata me todo o site por causa dessa div, que faço?

Comment: Cria uma nova pergunta com esse problema.

Comment: So posso fazer uma nova pergunta daqui a 2 dias, e precisava de ajuda

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19325/discussion-between-jorge-b-and-barofscas).

Comment: Sera que me poderia continuar a ajudar naquele problema que lhe disse no bate papp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se a tua ideia é ir buscar o nome do ficheiro assim

```
$new_texto = strip_tags(trim($_POST['new_texto']));
```

não funciona porque é um ficheiro.

Deverias ou aproveitar o `$nome` em vez de `$new_texto`:

<strike>`$new_texto = strip_tags(trim($_POST['new_texto']));`</strike>

`'".mysql_real_escape_string(`<strike>`$new_texto`</strike>`$nome)."',`

Ou então usar diretamente o nome do ficheiro:

```
$new_texto = $_FILES['new_texto']['name'];
```